# Messagebox not showing up

Tags: python, tkinter

I don't know why but my message box isn't showing up. There should be a menubar at the top with a "Help" button that should pop up with a message box. But all this code shows is my calculator minus the menubar. Is there something missing or wrong with my code? I have looked over it multiple times and I have no idea what went wrong. It looks just fine to me since everything else is working BUT my message box... What do I do to fix this problem?

this is my code:

```
        self.menubar = Menu(self)
        def about():
            messagebox.showinfo(title = "About", message = "Hello")
            return
        self.helpMenu = Menu(self.menubar)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label = "Help", menu=self.helpMenu)
        self.helpMenu.add_command(label = "About", command=about)
        root.config(menu=self.menubar)
```

Comment: Your title says that a messagebox isn't showing, but your question seems to be saying that the problem is actually with the menubar not showing. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the `root.config(menu = menubar)` in `if __ name __ == '__ main __'` then the help menu will show up.